# Need bootstrap Popover to work on table row level from an <a> in table column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have table with rows and 3 columns and every row has a class **search**, and in one my columns, I have an anchor tag(class="testpopover") and what I want is, on hover over an tag, a `Popover` should appear with some info at row level.

**Bit of Code**

```
$('.testpopover').live('hover', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.search').popover({ 'trigger': 'hover', 'placement': 'bottom', 'container': 'body', 'html': true });
});
```

what I expect is, when user hover over an  tag, it should trigger `search` popover but whats happening is initially, popover dont appear on hovering over any table row but once I hover over  tag of any row, `popover` starts appearing at hovering any table row. (starts appearing at row level rather than hovering over  tag only)

Can someone please guide me in right direction where i might be going wrong?

I tried creating a fiddle for my problem but dont know how to import bootstrap libraries in it.

My table structure looks like this

```
<tr id="4329690" class="search" data-title="Header" data-content=" Test Data">
<td class="">Data1</td>
<td class="">Data2</td>
<td class=""><a class="testpopover"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button class="popButton" id = "myPopover" rel="popover" data-toggle="popover" data-content="I'm a popover!">I do nothing!</button>
<button id = "myTrigger" data-src="#myPopover">Click me</button>

<script>
$('#myTrigger').click(function(){
  $($(this).data("src")).popover('toggle');
});
$(function() {
  $('.popButton').popover({
    trigger: "manual",
    placement: "top"
  });
});
</script>
```

**Code Edited to be a remote trigger**

with working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/vEzDp/2

Comment: kingdamian: I can replicate what your solution suggest, but what i want is when i hover over <a>, I get popover at table row (to user it should look like ````popover```` is bound to table row instead of <a> tag in one of the columns)

Comment: @Jay Ignore what I had before, just did ANOTHER edit that actually works correctly.